# Merge two nested lists of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, pyyaml

I want to merge two nested objects so that the 2nd is layed out on top of the 1st. This is for a `kubectl` config yaml but it could be any nested object that has a combination of `list`s, `dict`s and simple data types. eg:

```yaml
# yaml 1:
containers:
  - volumeMounts:
      - name: external-stroage-1
        mountPath: /mnt/stroage_1
        readOnly: true
```

```yaml
# Yaml 2
containers:
  - name: cron
    volumeMounts:
      - name: internal-storage
        mountPath: /mnt/data
```

And the merged object would be:

```yaml
containers:
  - name: cron
  - volumeMounts:
      - name: external-stroage-1
        mountPath: /mnt/stroage_1
        readOnly: true
      - name: internal-storage
        mountPath: /mnt/data
```

And here is what I have so far:

```py
def merge(object_one, object_two):
    assert type(object_one) == type(object_two), "Mismatched types"

    if isinstance(object_one, dict):
        for key in object_two:
            if key in object_one:
                object_one[key] = merge(object_one[key], object_two[key])
            else:
                object_one[key] = object_two[key]
    elif isinstance(object_one, list):
        for item in object_two:
            object_one.append(item) # <<<<< when should I overwrite instead of append?
    else:
        return object_two

    return object_one
```

Most of this can be done with simple recursion. Its easy to identify where an item should be inserted in a `dict` since it's indexed by keys. But how do you identify if two items should be merged when you have a `list` of objects (if the list order isn't guaranteed to be the same)? AKA, how do I determine if an item in a list needs to be overwritten vs appended? As it stands now, all list items are appended which leads to a bad merge:

```yaml
containers:
  - volumeMounts:
      - name: external-stroage-1
        mountPath: /mnt/stroage_1
        readOnly: true
      - name: external-stroage-2
        mountPath: /mnt/stroage_2
  - name: cron
    volumeMounts:  # This item should have been merged instead of being repeated
      - name: internal-storage
        mountPath: /mnt/data
```

Comment: I don't think you are lookiing at it the right way.  Instead of seeing sub items as lists, you should see them as dictionaries like `{"containers": {"volumeMounts": { "name":  "external-storage_1",  "readonly": True, "mountPath": "/mnt/storage_1" }, "name": "cron"}}`

Comment: I don't really get to pick the type. I just recursively work my way up to the leafs of the yaml structure. I just have to work with the structure the yaml gives me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a bit more bloated than I was hoping, and has to make a big assumption about the yaml structure, which is to assume two `dict` items within a list are the same item if they have a `name` key and matching values (which is common in our kubectl yamls). But with that assumption, this did the job:

```py
def merge(object_one, object_two):
    """
    Recursively merge object_two over object one. This is not universal and makes some assumptions based on typical structure of kubectl/plato yamls
    """
    assert type(object_one) == type(object_two), f"Mismatched types for object_one '{object_one}' and object_two {object_two}"

    if isinstance(object_one, dict):
        # If two dicts have a "name" field, and they match, its assumed they are the same field
        if 'name' in object_one.keys() and 'name' in object_two.keys():
            if object_one['name'] == object_two['name']:
                return object_two

        # Add missing keys to object_one
        object_one = {**object_one, **{k: v for k, v in object_two.items() if k not in object_one}}
        found = []

        # If
        for key in {x for x in object_one if x in object_two}:
            if (tmp := merge(object_one[key], object_two[key])) is not None:
                object_one[key] = tmp
                found.append(True)
            else:
                found.append(False)

        # If none is returned, the object is merged from 1 level up
        if not all(found):
            return None

    elif isinstance(object_one, list):
        # Compare every list element against the 2nd object, if no match is found, return None
        for index_two in range(len(object_two)):
            found = []
            for index in range(len(object_one)):
                try:
                    if tmp := merge(object_one[index], object_two[index_two]):
                        object_one[index] = tmp
                        found.append(True)
                    else:
                        found.append(False)
                except Exception:
                    pass

            # If None is returned, the object is merged from 1 level up
            if not any(found):
                object_one.append(object_two[index_two])
    else:
        # If both objects dont' match, return None which signals to the previous stack to merge one level up
        if object_one == object_two:
            return object_one
        return 

    return object_one
```